# Python packages not installed separately for different venv environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**TL;DR**
Would like to run Jupyter notebooks with different python setups. Python packages always install globally. Don't understand why.**\TL;DR**

I would like to run Jupyter notebooks with different python setups using `venv`. See here for the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Python 3.6 is already installed on my system

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Using the following commands I have created two virtual environments:

```
$ python3 -m venv --without-pip Documents/venv/test01
$ python3 -m venv --without-pip Documents/venv/test02
```

Following this [guide](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) I tried setting up different kernels for each notebook with

```
$ source activate test01
(Documents/venv/test02) $ python -m ipykernel install --user --name test01 --display-name test01
```

However, the second command failed with

```
/Users/dominik/Documents/venv/test02/bin/python: No module named ipykernel
```

So, I deactivated my venv and ran the same command outside the venv which succeeded

```
$ source deactivate test01
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name test01 --display-name test01
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name test02 --display-name test02
```

Inside my Jupyter notebook I can see the different kernels now:
[new kernels available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MdFQ.png)

Now I'm creating a new notebook using test01 kernel. Inside the notebook, I try to add a module which is not available in Python by default:

```
$ import mord
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a00d777a7e47> in <module>()
----> 1 import mord

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mord'
```

This is as expected. I then go about to installing that package into my test01 environment using pip

```
$ source activate Documents/venv/test01
(Documents/venv/test01) $ pip install mord
```

After restarting my test01 kernel the import error disappears - as expected. However - and now this is my question - when I `import mord` package on a `test02` notebook, **there is no import error either. Why is that?**

I would expect that `mord` package was only installed for `test01`. However, it seems to be installed globally.

Looking at the venv folders it shows that nothing was added specifically to those projects
[venv folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiTaA.png)

The `pyvenv.cfg` file seems also unchanged.

```
home = /Users/dominik/anaconda/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.6.1
```

**Can anyone give me some pointers what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: okay, hope it helps

Comment: Your hint about not installed pip was very helpful. I used `--without-pip` because I got an error without that parameter (zero exit status 1)

I have now installed pip manually using
    `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

Still figuring out how Jupyter fits into this.
E.g. when I start Jupyter I can see all different kernels (test01, test02 and the default python3 kernel). So that is still confusing me. And also I haven't fully understood yet, when which combination finds which packages and not.

Comment: you could check python executable file path int the [`kernel.json` file in kernelspecs](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernelspecs), to see which virtualenv it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you created virtualenv with `--without-pip` flag, there is no `pip` executable in the virtual environment, you used system `pip` to install package.

basically, virtual environment not involved in your setup, even though there are two kernel specs, they all created with virtualenv deactivated.

setup steps recommend: create virtualenv without `--without-pip` option; install `ipykernel` for each of your virtual environments, which means, install while virtualenv is activated; create kernel spec from corresponding virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

After georgexsh had pointed me in the right direction regarding the `--without-pip` flag, this is how I solved it in my case:

Create two virtual environments

```
$ python -m venv --without-pip Documents/venv/test01
$ python -m venv --without-pip Documents/venv/test02
```

I am still using the `--without-pip` flag, because the command otherwise produces an error message

The following steps are executed for each of the environments `test01`, `test02`:

Activate virtual environment and install pip manually

```
$ source Documents/venv/test01/bin/activate
(test01) $ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Install and run Jupyter inside the virtual environment

```
(test01) $ pip install jupyter
(test01) $ jupyter notebook
```

After having completed the above steps for both environments, I tested installing a package only in one of the environments

Activate the environment you want to install to first (if not activated already)

```
$ source Documents/venv/test01/bin/activate
(test01) $ pip install numpy
```

`numpy` package is now only available to the Jupyter version installed in `test01` environment.

If found that installing a dedicated kernel per each environment was optional (for my purpose). Anyway, here are the steps to run in an activated environment:

```
(test01) $ pip install ipykernel
(test01) $ python -m ipykernel install --user --name test01 --display-name test01
```

Now within Jupyter you can also create notebooks with different kernel types.